# How to tell how many displays a motherboard supports

Tags: multiple-monitors, motherboard

If it's not explicit in the spec, is there a way to tell how many monitors a motherboard will support?

For example, the [MAXIMUS VI FORMULA](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/MAXIMUS_VI_FORMULA/#specifications) motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

The motherboard has a HDMI and DISPLAYPORT connectors plus 3  pcie x16 slots so you could put 3 video cards in there and 2 from integrated video card.  ATI/AMD has eyefinity cards which support as many as 6 monitors each.  The normal ATI card has 4 connectors. If you have has 3 x16 cards with 4 monitors ea then 12 monitors, but as high as 3 *6 or 18 monitors.  Adding 2 for the onboard video gets you between 14 and 20 monitors.

Here is a 6 monitor card for example:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814129274

Note however, if you attempt to game,cad, or other heavy duty graphics you will need the best video cards money can buy to run 14-20 monitors.  For web surfing or other low end jobs it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The manual is not clear on whether or not the HDMI and DisplayPort can be used at the same time.  My assumption is that only 1 can be active at a time.  You would need to contact their technical support for this answer.

This is a nice motherboard, I would recommend getting a decent video card, and taking full advantage of the PCI Express 16x port.  Then you have a full range of options for dual monitors...DVI, HDMI, DisplayPort....